# activate functions only when a bool is true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, boolean

I want that when it becomes a bool it becomes false the conditions indicate inside "if" they cancel.
I have this situation where floats remain altered by the bool even when it is false.

```
float x = 2;
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) b = true;
if (b == true) { x = 3);

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift) b = false;
```

Isn't there a way to assert X to its original value, without adding X = 2 to b = false ..?

Comment: could you please add your actual code, that won't even compile. and please rework you question, your text doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float x = 2f;
float xfall = 2f;

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    b = true;
}
else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    b = false;
    x = xfall;
}

if(b)
{
    x = 3f;
}
```

A lot of your code cannot be even used, next time try to make it clearer for people to read.

Another thing to note is that you do not have to if(b == true) if(b) will return the same thing because it is the same line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator to simplify it somewhat if that's what you mean

```
x = b ? 3 : 2;
```